# Rails 3.2.1 `bundle install --path vendor` equivalent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

Would the command, `bundle install --path lib` in Rails 3.2.1 be equivalent to `bundle install --path vendor` in previous rails version?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an old question, but isn't this what `bundle install --deployment` is for?